# Function parameters as pointers and return value in C

Tags: c, pointers

In the function i need to pass in myFlg and somVar as input parameters. They are modified withing the function and then returned newLevel.

Do i pass in pointers for myFlg and somVar and how do i do that. The flg and counter need to be updated inside the function but they are not globals. So pass in two parameters/pointers and return a value, one return value and two modified values/pointers.

```
     in flags.h
#define FlagReg1set_u         0b01000001

typedef union
{
    struct
    {
        uint8_t Flg1 : 1;
        uint8_t Flg2 : 1;
        uint8_t Flg3 : 1;
        uint8_t Flg4 : 1;
        uint8_t Flg5 : 1;
        uint8_t Flg6 : 1;
        uint8_t my_Flg : 1;
        uint8_t foo : 1;
    } bits;
    uint8_t byte;
} FlagReg1_t = FlagReg1set_u;


in level.c
uint16_t level(uint8_t Flag, uint8_t SomeVariable, uint8_t SomeCount)
{

    static uint16_t newLevel = SomeVariable;
    static uint8_t count = SomeCount;
    static uint8_t somVar;

if (FlagReg1.bits.my_Flg == 1)
    {
    /* do something */
    newLevel = 0xFFFF;
    }
else
    {
      FlagReg1.bits.my_Flg = 0
    }

if (somVar == SomeVariable)
    {
    count = 0;
    }
    else
    {
    count++;
    }

return newLevel
}

in main .c
#include "flags.h"

main()
{
/* Variable Declaration */
uint16_t level(uint8_t Flag, uint8_t SomeVariable, uint8_t SomeCount);

    uint8_t count = 0;
    uint8_t ownlevel;
    uint16_t newLevel;



    level(FlagReg1_t my_Flg, ownlevel, count);

    if (newLevel == 0)
    {
    //do something
    }
    else
    {
    //do something
    }

}
```

Comment: I would appreciate if you have picked snake case scripting.For various reasons myFlg is better as my_flag .

Comment: You also have various errors.For example.  typedef union flag_t {bla bla} flag;You missed the type.Same for struct.Also you don't have clear understanding in what a union is.

Comment: This is just an example code, not real code, I am looking for help with how to do what I need, i.e. return a value from a function, change a variable and struct within the function which will keep the changes outside the function. The use of the union was to be able to set all the bits to a default, I left that out.

Comment: well since you tag C , then you better use C and not "test" code.

Answer (score 0):

Well excuses to the community I use answer space , this is more a comment but I need the tools to explain.
So , eumac , the usual purpose of a union is:

```
typedef union eumac_un_t
{
    struct eumac_str
    {
        uint8_t flag_4;
        uint8_t flag_3;
        uint8_t flag_2;
        uint8_t flag_1;
    };
int the_flag;
}eumac_un;
```

This takes 4 bytes (a memory area) , stores the same data which can be retrieved in all the various ways.
Example if you store

```
eumac_un_t.eumac_str.flag_1 = 150  //(1001 0110)
eumac_un_t.eumac_str.flag_2 = 20  //(0001 0100)
```

what you get for

```
eumac_un_t.the_flag == 5270 //its 0000 0000 - 0000 0000 - 0001 0100 - 1001 0110
```

This is why we use a union.So in your case you won't need it.Is that clear??

Now in your case , usually you pass as pointers when you have an array.If flag is just an integer , then you can simply pass it as an integer.

So yes , exactly the function you mention is very nice

```
    uint16_t level(FlagReg1_t *ptrToFlagReg1, uint8_t *SomeVariable, uint8_t *SomeCount)
{
    ptrToFlagReg1->something = something;
    ptrToFlagReg1->something_else = something_else;
    return number_of_something;
}
```

Integers don't really have to be passed as pointers if there's no need to.

```
uint8_t SomeVariable, uint8_t SomeCount
```

Comment: The union is already been used in this project that I need to modify. Could you direct me/help with the use of the pointers for this case, pass in a flag, a count and return a value but also modifying flag and count. Should the function be something like this, uint16_t level(FlagReg1_t *ptrToFlagReg1, uint8_t *SomeVariable, uint8_t *SomeCount), and what will the declaration in main() be for the flg, count ?

Comment: Just to clarify I have changed the original code example, is this what is needed?